# Implementation of Instant Chat Application in android using Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on the creation of instant chat application in android using Google Cloud Messaging .I have studied the following links:

1. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client
2. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream
3. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/upstream

Still i am not able to understand how can i use it?

Do i need to implement Socket programming also?

I do not know where to specify the IP address of the application server where i have to send the messages.Can anybody tell me the simple way to create messaging Application using GCM.

Please help me to understand the work flow of GCM .

Answer (score 0):

Seems no effort in googling .

> first of all brush up your concept what is GCM and how it is work .

These are some of the links you should refer [GCM Intro](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

for GCM Chat You should refer [IM using GCM](http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/instachat/)

let me know if you have any query.